# How to increase the strength of my wireless signal?

Tags: networking, signal, wep, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improve Wireless Signal](https://superuser.com/questions/45960/improve-wireless-signal)

Hello! I have some wireless connection from my college through the dormitory where i am living. The connection is really strong in the living room but weak in my room. Is there any way to extend the signal or enhance it in my room?

I don't know the type of router that they are using since it is locked in the building. Though i was wondering if there is a way through an antenna or something.

Please if you can describe to me the procedure in details i would be grateful.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you complained to the school?  They may just not realize the signal penetration is poor.  (Alternatively, do other people have problems with their laptop/phone/whatever-you're-using in the same room? It could just be your device.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improve Wireless Signal](http://superuser.com/questions/45960/improve-wireless-signal) or [How can I beam my Wifi signal across the street?](http://superuser.com/questions/227056/how-can-i-beam-my-wifi-signal-across-the-street)

Comment: Also check: [Are there any devices to increase the range of a WiFi network?](http://superuser.com/questions/341294/are-there-any-devices-to-increase-the-range-of-a-wifi-network).

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a Router that can be flashed with the [DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), this firmware has an option to repeat a wireless signal thus extending your range.

From experience, you will need a powerful router in order to make the signal strength worth using.

Comment: You can also just buy a dedicated repeater, but the college might not appreciate EITHER of these approaches.

Comment: Yes that's right, mainly it states in the Terms that a router can not be used.