# Are there any devices to increase the range of a WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

Are there any devices that do not need to be physically connected to a network (only to a power source) and just take any WiFi signal they receive and reproduce it in order to increase the range of a WiFi network?

If so, how are such devices called? Google just gives me strange DIY guides if I search for "WiFi extender".

Comment: I would Google for "wifi repeater"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a wireless repeater, such as the Netgear [WN3000RP](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/wireless-range-extenders/WN3000RP.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's called wireless repeater. In fact is just another wireless router configured in a special way. Check these links:

- [Universal Wireless Repeater](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater)
- [Repeater Bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge)

I'm linking to the DD-WRT firmware page but some routers have this feature built in. Depending on your case you could just upgrade from 802.11g to 802.11n to increase your range/speed.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [wireless repeater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater) (also called wireless range extender).

---

It takes an existing signal from a wireless router or access point and rebroadcasts it to create a second network. So when two or more hosts have to be connected with one another over the Wi-Fi and the distance is too long for a direct connection to be established, a wireless repeater is used to bridge the gap.

[image: AP as Repeater]