# How do you increase wifi adapter power?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Is there a way to boost usb wifi adapters someway to get more power or signal strength? I am currently using alfa awus036nha wifi adapter with a 16dbi yagi antenna.

Is there like an amplifier to increase the range of the wifi adapter itself instead of the router? Does something like this work? [4000mw wifi adapter amplifier](http://www.ebay.com/itm/High-Power-4W-4000mW-2-4Ghz-Wifi-b-g-n-booster-Amplifier-for-Router-AP-Adapter-/321242547379?pt=US_Networking_Boosters_Extenders_Antennas&hash=item4acb8c44b3) or something simliar?

Comment: which OS? I only know how to do this in Linux

Comment: Im running windows 7 and ubuntu both 64 bit.

Comment: See: [Are there any devices to increase the range of a WiFi network?](http://superuser.com/questions/341294/are-there-any-devices-to-increase-the-range-of-a-wifi-network).

Answer (score 0):

Newer 802.11n Wi-Fi routers are increasingly coming with internal antennas. There are some that still have or support external ones, and these antennas can often be upgraded. Consider a hi-gain antenna, which you can position so that the Wi-Fi signal goes in the direction you want. Hawking Technology offers the HAI15SC Hi-Gain Wireless Corner Antenna. Though, we have yet to test it; Hawking claims it boosts wireless signal strength from a standard 2dBi to 15dBi. Antennas like these can attach to most routers that have external antennas connectors. Hi-gain or "booster" antennas range in pricing from $40 to $100 dollars.